# Mapbox map is not loading and not responding

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am using Mapbox JS library, in `localhost` its working fine

[image]

but when I upload my site on a live server the map does not get the current location and not loading correctly(sky blue map).

Any suggestions, did I miss something?

[image]

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @JesperMartinez the code is shown below in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="address">Location</label>
                <div id="map" style="margin: 0 auto;"></div>
                <script>
                mapboxgl.accessToken = 'ACCESS-TOKEN';
                var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                    container: 'map', // container id
                    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
                    center: [-96, 37.8], // starting position
                    zoom: 3 // starting zoom
                });

                var geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl();
                map.addControl(geolocate);
                geolocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
                      lon = e.coords.longitude;
                      lat = e.coords.latitude
                      var position = [lon, lat];
                      //alert(lon + " " + lat);
                });


                </script>
            </div>
```